# Anisotropic semisimple groups with no real compact factor

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

Let $F$ be a number field, and let $G$ be a semi-simple connected, anisotropic algebraic group over $F$ which is $F$-simple (or almost simple, the question is agnostic to isogenies). Suppose further that $G(F_v)$ is non-compact for each archimedean place $v$.

**Question**: Must $G$ be either exceptional type, type $D_4$, or the norm 1 group of a division algebra?

I **think** I can prove this from the classification in Platonov-Rapinchuk plus the Hasse-Minkowski theorem, but would be much happier with a reference, or better an explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: I think **Yes**, $G$ must be the norm one group of a division algebra.  Not of type $D_4$: any group of type $D_4$ over a $p$-adic field is isotropic! See the paper by Tits in the Boulder volume. (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math. vol. 9).

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464648/anisotropic-semisimple-groups-with-no-real-compact-factor#comment1208365_464648), in fact the only anisotropic simple groups over a $p$-adic field are of type $\mathsf A_n$.  But the problem doesn't seem to put any condition on the behaviour of $G$ at the non-Archimedean places—or am I missing it?

Comment: For classical groups, the fact that a quadratic form in $5$ or more variables over a $p$-adic field is isotropic seems to me to say that the only _classical_ groups that are anisotropic without being real anisotropic at any place would be type $A_n$ with a division algebra at some finite place. But I'm thinking case-wise, rather than intrinsically...

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @MikhailBorovoi, the paper seems to be about local fields, not global fields. Is there a theorem that for a group to be anisotropic it must be anisotropic at some finite place?

Comment: @paulgarrett I checked case by case in Platonov Rapinchuk and there are seemingly open questions with the case of skew-hermitian forms left quaternion algebras of low rank. Could you please explain how you’re thinking of it?

Comment: Last thing: @MikhailBorovoi

I think the D4 case must be excluded because the extra automorphisms make things weird. Also because this paper - example 11.8 says it provides an anisotropic Q-algebra that’s isotropic over the reals. https://msp.org/pjm/1992/156-2/pjm-v156-n2-p02-s.pdf

Comment: @jacob: You are right and I am not right, as example 11.8 in the linked paper shows.